# -join "," only grabbing the first item and not combining items with comma

Tags: powershell

I am running the following script but the -join "," for the owners is only returning the first result and not combining them with commas:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'Application.Read.All'
$results = @()
#Get-AzureADApplication -All $true | %{ 
#Get-MgApplication | %{ 
Get-MgApplication -filter "AppID eq 'xyzxyzxyzxyz'" | % {
                             $app = $_
                             $owner = Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $_.ID -Top 1
                             $app.PasswordCredentials | 
                                %{ 
                                    $results += [PSCustomObject] @{
                                            
                                            DisplayName = $app.DisplayName; 
                                            AppID = $app.AppID;
                                            CredentialType = "PasswordCredentials";
                                            ExpiryDate = $_.EndDateTime;
                                            #StartDate = $_.StartDate;
                                            #KeyID = $_.KeyId;
                                            Type = 'NA';
                                            #Usage = 'NA';
               THis Line Here -->           Owners = $owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName -join ', ';
                                        }
                                 }   
                          }
$results
```

Anyone have a quick fix to get the owners to process the join and list all owners with a comma?
Owners = $owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName -join ', ';

Comment: Does `($owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName) -join ', '` make a difference?

Comment: Hi Abraham, it does not.

Comment: Is `$owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName` actually an array to begin with? Please show what `Write-Host $owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName.GetType().Name` outputs.

Comment: PS C:\Users\XYZ> Write-Host $owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName.GetType().Name
String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you code  `$owner = Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $_.ID -Top 1`

A join is useless because you are limiting the amount of owner returned to 1 in all cases. Remove the `-Top1` from your code and everything will work as expected.

```
 $owner = Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $_.ID 
 #... 
 $owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName -join ', '
```

Comment: Doh! Yeah that makes sense. Thanks, removing that gives me all of them.